# ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed "spring"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am getting an error when I am trying to run my spring app. Kindly help me out.

ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed "spring"

[image]

root-context.xml

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

```
<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->


<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="root"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.demo.login.beans.Customer</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="customerDao" class="com.demo.login.dao.CustomerDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="customerService" class="com.demo.login.services.CustomerServiceImpl">
    <property name="customerDao" ref="customerDao"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Your linked screenshot shows a more complete stack trace. I'd suggest providing that.

Comment: I apologize for that silly mistake..!

Comment: kindly check the screen-shoot. @alexanderific